# How to draw bent arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

In this image below,  a bent arrow is drawn using following line

```
\documentclass[x11names]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\let\familydefault\rmdefault

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,decorations.markings,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\def\myrad{0.75cm}% radius of the circle
\def\myang{45}% angle for the arc
\tikzstyle{rarrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\newcommand{\cercle}[6]{
\node[circle,inner sep=0,minimum size={2*#2}](a) at (#1) {};
\draw[#6,line width=#5] (a.#3) arc (#3:{#3+#4}:#2);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 0mm,
  my angle/.style = {draw, thick, -stealth, 
                     angle radius=1cm,"$\theta$"}
                    ]
% Gridline
\draw [step=0.5cm,draw=gray] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
\node (ref1) [circle,draw=none,fill=red,inner sep=0pt,text width=0.001mm] at (-3.5,2.5) {};
\node (ref2) [circle,draw=none,fill=blue,inner sep=0pt,text width=0.01mm] at (-4,-1.5) {};

% BackGround Boxes
\node (BG1) [draw=gray, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.2, thick,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=5cm,anchor=north west] at (-4,4){};
\node (BG2) [draw=gray, fill=gray!10, thick,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=2cm,anchor=north west] at (-4,-1.5){};

% BG1
\node (BG1-Block1) [draw=none, fill=none, thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm] at (ref1.east) {$\mathbf{X}$};

\node (BG1-Block2) [draw=red, fill=red!10,thick, minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm,right=of BG1-Block1,xshift=1cm] {B1};
\node (BG1-Block21) [draw=red, fill=red!10,thick, minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm,below=of BG1-Block2,yshift=-0.5cm] {B2};
\node (BG1-Block22) [draw=none, fill= none, minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm,below=of BG1-Block21,yshift=-0cm] {$\vdots$};
\node (BG1-Block23) [draw=red, fill=red!10,thick, minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm,below=of BG1-Block22,yshift=-0.2cm] {Bn};

\node (BG1-Block3) [circle,draw=red, fill=red!10,thick, right=of BG1-Block2, xshift=1.5cm,inner sep=0pt,text width=0.75cm] {};
\node (BG1-Block4) [draw=none, fill=none, align=center] at (BG1-Block3.center) {$\mathbf{+}$};
\node (BG1-Block5) [draw=none, fill=none, thick,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=1cm, right=of BG1-Block4,xshift=1.5cm] {$\mathbf{Y}$};

\draw [rarrow] (BG1-Block1) -- (BG1-Block2);
\draw [rarrow] (BG1-Block2) -- node[above] {$\mathbf{Y}_1$} (BG1-Block3);
\draw [rarrow] (BG1-Block3) -- node[right] {} (BG1-Block5);

\node (ref3) [circle,draw=none,fill=green,inner sep=0pt,text width=1mm] at (-2.5,2.5) {};

\draw [rarrow]  (ref3) |- (BG1-Block21);
\draw [rarrow]  (ref3) |- (BG1-Block22);
\draw [rarrow]  (ref3) |- (BG1-Block23);

\draw [rarrow]  (BG1-Block21) -| (BG1-Block3.south west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code results in bent arrows that have right angles. Is it possible to draw  bent arrows, like one shown in green, that have angles less/more than 90?

[image]

Comment: Please add a _complete_ MWE!

Comment: An MWE should be complete but minimal. Most of that code isn't relevant to your question, as far as I can tell.

Comment: There's also a simpler way: `\draw [rarrow] (BG1-Block21.east) -- +(20pt,0) node[shift={(-10pt,-10pt)}, right] {$\mathbf{Y}_{2}$} -- (BG1-Block3.south west);` (I've a note also to my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=red, fill=pink] (Block2) {B2};
    \node[draw=red, fill=pink, circle, above right= of Block2] (plus) {+};
    \draw[->, thick, draw=green]  (Block2.east) -- ([xshift=20pt]Block2.east) node[above left] {$Y_{2}$} -- (plus);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*
With your (not so) minimal example:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\let\familydefault\rmdefault

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,decorations.markings,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

    \def\myrad{0.75cm}% radius of the circle
    \def\myang{45}% angle for the arc
    \tikzstyle{rarrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

    \newcommand{\cercle}[6]{
        \node[circle,inner sep=0,minimum size={2*#2}](a) at (#1) {};
        \draw[#6,line width=#5] (a.#3) arc (#3:{#3+#4}:#2);
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0mm,
    my angle/.style = {draw, thick, -stealth, 
        angle radius=1cm,"$\theta$"}
    ]
    % Gridline
    \draw [step=0.5cm,draw=gray] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
    \node (ref1) [circle,draw=none,fill=red,inner sep=0pt,text width=0.001mm] at (-3.5,2.5) {};
    \node (ref2) [circle,draw=none,fill=blue,inner sep=0pt,text width=0.01mm] at (-4,-1.5) {};

    % BackGround Boxes
    \node (BG1) [draw=gray, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.2, thick,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=5cm,anchor=north west] at (-4,4){};
    \node (BG2) [draw=gray, fill=gray!10, thick,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=2cm,anchor=north west] at (-4,-1.5){};

    % BG1
    \node (BG1-Block1) [draw=none, fill=none, thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm] at (ref1.east) {$\mathbf{X}$};

    \node (BG1-Block2) [draw=red, fill=red!10,thick, minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm,right=of BG1-Block1,xshift=1cm] {B1};
    \node (BG1-Block21) [draw=red, fill=red!10,thick, minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm,below=of BG1-Block2,yshift=-0.5cm] {B2};
    \node (BG1-Block22) [draw=none, fill= none, minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm,below=of BG1-Block21,yshift=-0cm] {$\vdots$};
    \node (BG1-Block23) [draw=red, fill=red!10,thick, minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm,below=of BG1-Block22,yshift=-0.2cm] {Bn};

    \node (BG1-Block3) [circle,draw=red, fill=red!10,thick, right=of BG1-Block2, xshift=1.5cm,inner sep=0pt,text width=0.75cm] {};
    \node (BG1-Block4) [draw=none, fill=none, align=center] at (BG1-Block3.center) {$\mathbf{+}$};
    \node (BG1-Block5) [draw=none, fill=none, thick,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=1cm, right=of BG1-Block4,xshift=1.5cm] {$\mathbf{Y}$};

    \draw [rarrow] (BG1-Block1) -- (BG1-Block2);
    \draw [rarrow] (BG1-Block2) -- node[above] {$\mathbf{Y}_1$} (BG1-Block3);
    \draw [rarrow] (BG1-Block3) -- node[right] {} (BG1-Block5);

    \node (ref3) [circle,draw=none,fill=green,inner sep=0pt,text width=1mm] at (-2.5,2.5) {};

    \draw [rarrow]  (ref3) |- (BG1-Block21);
    \draw [rarrow]  (ref3) |- (BG1-Block22);
    \draw [rarrow]  (ref3) |- (BG1-Block23);

    \draw [rarrow] (BG1-Block21.east) -- ([xshift=20pt]BG1-Block21.east) node[shift={(-10pt,-10pt)}, right] {$\mathbf{Y}_{2}$} -- (BG1-Block3.south west);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or even simpler:

```
\draw [rarrow] (BG1-Block21.east) -- +(20pt,0) node[shift={(-10pt,-10pt)}, right] {$\mathbf{Y}_{2}$} -- (BG1-Block3.south west);
```

[image]